# Regex to match alphanumeric characters, allowing underscores only in the middle

Tags: regex

Right now, I have a regular expression that looks like this:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
```

It matches all alphanumeric characters currently. I want it to be able to match with an expression that has a middle underscore, but not if there are consecutive underscores, leading underscores, or trailing underscores.
Ie

- `test__` (not ok)
- `_test` (not ok)
- `test_` (not ok)
- `test_string` (ok)

What would the regular expression look like?

Comment: Like this? `[A-Za-z](?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*` Note: Replace the ending * with ? if you only want to allow one underscore

Comment: What about strings that don't have any underscores in between?

Comment: @CAustin They should be matched also

Comment: So, matching this is ok ? "_`test`"

Comment: And what about variables that aren't strings?

Comment: @x15 Yes, that's ok

Comment: This ok ? "\_\_\_`test_string`\_\_\_"

Comment: What about just `test` or `te_st_str_ing`?

Comment: @x15 isn't that covered by "leading/trailing underscores"?

Comment: Consecutive, leading, and trailing underscores should not be matched.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - The question seems to be about substring matching, trying to find out.  Like can the highlight here be matched ? "\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_`test`\_\_\_\_\_\_"

Comment: @x15 No, that shouldn't be OK because it has consecutive underscores.

Comment: @DeviousKoala What about my examples?

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, those should match because there are no leading or trailing underscores.

Comment: Follow @dvo advice `^[A-Za-z](?:_?[A-Za-z0-9])*$`

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ Wrong.....

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ Yours appears to be correct, unless there is some obscure case I don't know of.

Comment: @DeviousKoala - It can't be right since it forces an underscore in the middle and only allows a single one, when it is stated it's optional and can have match many underscores as long as none are consecutive.

Comment: @x15 ^[A-Za-z](?:_?[A-Za-z0-9])* is correct. Post that and I'll give you best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

To make `_` optional

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

To allow more than one `_`

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+_{0,1})+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Comment: Note that this solution **requires** and a middle underscore which is not the same as **allowing** a middle underscore. This doesn't make the answer wrong, but you should take this in consideration when using this answer. Further more it doesn't allow more then one underscore, so `this_wont_match`.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't fit OP's requirements according to the comments on the question, so I'm not sure why this was selected as the answer.

Comment: You guys are right. I just tried it out and it didn't work as expected. I'll still pick a better answer.

Comment: @3limin4t0r so it can do ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$

Comment: @DeviousKoala see edits

Comment: You could replace `_{0,1}` with `_?` to shorten it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*
```

Should meet the requirements. This uses what you already had and adds the option to use an underscore if followed by at least one or more `[A-Za-z0-9]` characters.

[image: regex diagram]

You might want to anchor the solution with `^` and `$` to the beginning and ending of the string, but this depends on your use-case.

Comment: Can get slightly better performance with `^(?!\d)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$` but I like the approach. +1

Comment: @x15 Hadn't thought of that, I'll leave it as a comment though since I'll have to regenerate the diagram while the result is the same.